# Qn: Getting Around Windows File Lockup Property -- using FileHandling in Java or C#

Tags: c#, java, windows, file-handling

I am encountering a problem in developing a software for my business. The task I am trying to achieve is that, I need to update a file (.txt) while that file is being constantly accessed by another program.

The ultimate setting is this: I will have a software running, constantly reading the content of a feed file (call it info.txt). I have another script running, constantly updating the feed file (info.txt).

I realized the serious conflict in using the file after I implemented the above setting. With the software (call it AAA) running, I can't make an edit to info.txt even manually. I open up info.txt, make a change, and click save, windows return an error message: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." If I try to delete info.txt, the error message is "the action can't be completed because the file is open in AAA.exe".
When I run my (java) script that constantly updates info.txt, the file IO exception is: java.io.FileNotFoundException: info.txt (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

The software AAA is not that well developped. (It's a foreign software to my enterpise so I can't modify its behavior/source code.) The way it is accessing files locks up the file completely. I thought of temperarily pointing away the reference to info.txt in the software's profile files to allow a temparory edit, but this approach would fail because with AAA running (and I need it to), I can't make any change to any file it's using.

I consulted one of the main developer of software AAA. He acknowledges this is a problem right now, he would improve it in next release. But meanwhile I would like the set up to work. He told me he programs with .NET, and he provided a line that could help me to get around my problem:

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"info.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

Supposedly, by supplying these arguments, this filestream are allowed to be shared on both writes and reads.

I am a java programmer, and I've had no experience with .NET. However I did some research and learning, I realized his code is the syntex of C#, which runs in the CLR of .NET framework. I set up C# on my computer and studied some C# beginer tutorial, and comes up with the following script, hoping to solve my problem.

If it's really true that C# allows to change the access property of a file at a fundamental level, I would open up the filestream of info.txt, allowing it to be shared with both read and write. Once I do that, I can run my script of updating info.txt, and then run the software AAA that keeps refreshing info.txt.

Trying to achieve the above implementation, I come up with a C# script:

================================================

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class CopyFeed
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string fileName1 = "info.txt";  
        string fileName2 = "info2.txt";


        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@fileName1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,             FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter sw = null;

        // attempting to unlock part of the file, didn't work
        /*
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(@fileName2);
        fs.Unlock(0, contents.Length * 2);
        */

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Copying Feed...");

            string contents = File.ReadAllText(@fileName2);

            try
            {
                sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.Write(contents);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CopyFeed :: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sw != null)
                {

                    sw.Flush();
                    //sw.Close();

                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Pausing For 2 sec...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        }



    }
}
```

================================================

Supposedly, I will have my java script constantly updating info2.txt . Then I will have this C# script constantly copying the entire content of info2.txt into info.txt.
 I wish to seek help with this post in 2 aspects:

1. The above script is still buggy, because all it does is keep appending to the file info.txt. I wish to find a way that I can clear the content of file at the start of every iteration and just copy over the content of file2. Right now if I execute the script, it will create a infinitely large file as time goes.
2. Based on the description above, is my solution going to work? Do I have any better option? (with software AAA behaviour staying the same) Is there even a way to get around it?
3. Could I have find a solution using Java? does Java have file handling capability that interacts with Windows system in a more fundamental level and unlocks the file?

I've been working on this problem for the past few days and am really stuck. I would sincerely thank any one who offers any insight!

Comment: only you will know if the solution will work... did you test / debug the code that you currently have..???

Comment: Hi DJ Kraze, I tried to, but I failed to debug. That's one of the help I wish to ask for. I have little experience to C# and file handling in general. I donno how to make my C# script functioning there. I need a way to clear the file content before writing/copying over again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you if the method you describe works for accessing the locked file as I don't have such a scenario available for testing.

As for your question 1.):

You can clear the contents of a file with the static method [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) (namespace **System.IO**). This is the equivalent to the

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@fileName2);
```

in the C# code you posted.

Example:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test\test.txt", "");
```

or better

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test\test.txt", string.Empty);
```

Alternatively you can use the [setLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx) method of your FileStream with the value 0:

```
fs.SetLength(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

While your method will prevent a FileNotFoundException from occurring on your program, you should consider the potential of causing the same exception for other programs that attempt to access the file you are editing.

My work has a similar use case and we interface with version control instead of the file directly. This way, we can merge changes if concurrent edits are being made.

If you are not comfortable with this approach, you should at least alter your code to catch for System.IO.FileNotFoundExceptions instead of System.Exception.